# Search Wiki Library not found

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created one new page in the wiki library. The problem is, when I search the page that has been created, it shows the below error. How to solve this problem?

[error searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZq7T.png)

Answer (score 0):

The new page you created has not been crawled by search. You need to start a full crawl in your SharePoint server, please refer to the below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/start-pause-resume-or-stop-a-crawl